# Not sure how to approach using a Plan Validator on User to check if the Plan is at max allowable users Rails 4 Devise Invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-invitable, apartment-gem

Im building out a multi-tenant app in Rails 4 using the Apartment Gem, this is a subscription based application and limits the number of users by the plan type.

I have the following validation in my Plan Model (I'll paste the whole thing here), but I am unsure of how to validate this so that an admin or owner can not invite a user if the account is at max capacity?

**Plan.rb:**

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  # Enum & Constants
  enum plan_type: [:responder, :first_responder, :patrol_pro, :guardian]

  USER_LIMITS = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    #Plan Name      #Auth Users
    responder:        6,
    first_responder:  12,
    patrol_pro:       30,
    guardian:         60
  )

  # Before Actions

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :account, optional: true

  # Validations
  validate :must_be_below_user_limit

  # Custom Methods
  def user_limit
    USER_LIMITS[self.plan_type]
  end

  def must_be_below_user_limit
    if account.present? && persisted? && User.count < user_limit
     errors[:user_limit] = "can not more than #{user_limit} users"
   end
  end

end
```

Functionality wise I Want to make sure that the owner can not add a user if the user count for the associated account is more than the plan_type allows. if so I Want to flash a message saying please upgrade..

thanks in advance.. This is the bane of my existence!!

Comment: `account.present? && persisted? && account.users.count < user_limit`

Comment: You should check the users of that account, not all users.

Comment: In apartment this has its own shchema, so even if i tried to search all users app wide i cant

Comment: but you should use `>` instead of `<`, `account.present? && account.users.count > user_limit`

Comment: thanks, that was a typo lol.. either way from the Plan Model its not blocking the creation of new users thats what im trying to figure out how can i cann or use this elsewhere/

Comment: `def must_be_below_user_limit
    if account.present? &&  (account.users.count > user_limit)
     errors.add(:user_limit, "can not more than #{user_limit} users")
   end
  end`

Comment: But this will limit user creation from the Plan Model?

Comment: Disregard, this is limiting the users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126065/discussion-between-sravan-and-shawn-wilson).

Comment: Feel Free to place that in an answer and ill award best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have taken a wrong condition for the `user_limit` and remove the persisted? its not needed as you have taken, `account.present?`

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  # Enum & Constants
  enum plan_type: [:responder, :first_responder, :patrol_pro, :guardian]

  -----------------------

  # Custom Methods
  def user_limit
    USER_LIMITS[self.plan_type]
  end

  def must_be_below_user_limit 
    if account.present? && (account.users.count > user_limit)
     errors.add(:user_limit, "can not more than #{user_limit} users") 
    end
  end 

end
```